# Active Tag in Cucumber Java

Tags: maven, tags, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Is there anyway to identify which is the current running cucumber tag in Cucumber-Java for API testing?

I am using Cucumber-Java, along with TestNG. For grouping and executing in different environments, I am using cucumber tags.

The tags are given in feature level. Multiple tags have been specified for same feature. Like:

```
@regression-staging @regression-production
Feature: Add to cart

Scenario:
.
.
.
```

Same code is using for staging and production. And as build took I am using Maven. Since TestNG is used, the test is triggered from `RunTestNGTest` class that I wrote. Inside the `RunTestNGTest`, I have @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite methods.

The test is run using mvn command

`mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@regression-staging`

or
`mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@regression-production`

Is there anyway I can get which tag is currently running? (In my case, either one will be active at a time). I want to log which tag is currently using, and also want to use the same in the HTML report. I tried `scenario.getSourceTagNames();`, but that returns all the tags for the scenario, not the currently running one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access `cucumber.filter.tags` from your code like you would access any other system property:

```java
String myCurrentTag = System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.tags");
```

Now you can parse the value (split by commas or additionally remove `@` symbol, etc.)