# How to retrieve current tags being executed passed from runner file in Cucumber Selenium TestNg framework

Tags: maven, tags, cucumber, testng, runner

- `@ProdCheck @Login @Regression
- Feature: Login
- 
- Scenario: Successful Login
- Given Open Application and Enter "Testurl"
- When enter username "demo100" and password "test"
- Then Logout from the application
- 
- Runner:
- @CucumberOptions(
- strict = true,
- features = {"."},
- plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:./target/cucumber-reports/report.html/TestReport.html",
- ```
               "rerun:target/failedrerun.txt"},
  ```
- monochrome = true,
- glue = {"com.evry.stepdefs"},
- tags={"@Login"}
- ```
      )
  ```
- public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
- }
- 'Need to know how to retrieve current tags being executed during run time in WebDriverManager`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663606/active-tag-in-cucumber-java